# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-3

Esta aparecendo esse erro quando aperto F12, e o data-toggle="tooltip" do Bootstrap não aparece na pagina alguém pode me ajudar?

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (conf.js:39)
    at j (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
```

Comment: O que o teu F12 diz na lista de "sources"? O mais provável é que a definição de $.fn.tooltip não tenha sido carregada na sua página. Aliás, posta o texto da função que contém a linha 39 do arquivo `conf.js`.

Comment: $(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
});

Comment: Existe um arquivo na lista de arquivos carregados na aba "sources" chamado `tooltip.js`? Pelo que entendo do Bootstrap, este é o arquivo que tem a definição da `tooltip()`, embora ele normalmente seja carregado por dentro do `bootstrap.js`

Comment: Tem não, antes desse erro tem outro, Uncaught Error: Popover requires tooltip.js ,   bootstrap.js:41

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não incluiu o Bootstrap corretamente na sua página. Para tanto, ele precisa de uma *tag* `<script>` dentro da *tag* `<head>`, mais ou menos assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Minha página de Bootstrap</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/ecmascript" src="caminho/para/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/ecmascript">
            // funções da página...
```

E por aí vai. Note que, devido a algumas características (leia: *bugs*) de determinados navegadores antigos, as *tags* de `<script>` com um atributo `src` (isto é, aquelas que importam arquivos em vez de definir javascript no próprio HTML) têm que ter uma *tag* de fechamento explícita (isto é, não se pode dizer `<script type="text/ecmascript" scr="script.js" />`).

Tendo essa referência para o arquivo do Bootstrap, a `tooltip()` e as outras funções vão passar a funcionar.

Answer (score -1):

Esse problema deve estar ocorrendo por conflito de alguma chamada a mais de javascript, faça um teste, retire todos e coloque apena os abaixo:

```
<!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
<script src="../build/js/custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Fabio, o ideal e que testes e dúvidas sejam sugeridos por comentários

Answer (score -2):

Remova carregamentos duplicados do jQuery e/ou Bootstrap. Inspecione o código e localize os pontos onde ocorre carregamento do  mais de uma vez.